# Why won't this pass to the next component (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want the `Portfolio` class to take the `this.prompt` in `Title Bar` class.  I've been searching around for this for quite some time now but still haven't found a concrete solution for this.

Right now, all I have is a blank screen.

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <title>name name</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="body.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="firstBar"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <div id="portfolio">

    </div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="body.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
 var TitleBar = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return(
     <div className="jumbotron">
      <div className="container">
      <kbd className="fullName">name name</kbd>
        <button onClick={this.prompt} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>
      </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TitleBar/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));

var Portfolio = React.createClass({

  this.props.prompt(
    alert("hi");
  );

  render: function() {
    return(
      <p className="text-primary">Portfolio</p>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Portfolio prompt={this.prompt}/>, document.getElementById('portfolio'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is the following code, inside the `Portfolio` component:

```js
this.props.prompt(
    alert("hi");
);
```

This is just incorrect syntax for defining and/or using props. If you remove that, you will at least see the application rendered.

---

Now that you can see something, one way to solve your bigger problem is to not use a prop at all, but create an instance method in the `TitleBar` component. Here's an `index.js` that does that:

```jsx
var TitleBar = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    this.prompt = function() { alert('hi'); };

    return(
     <div className="jumbotron">
      <div className="container">
      <kbd className="fullName">name name</kbd>
        <button onClick={this.prompt} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>
      </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TitleBar/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));

var Portfolio = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return(
      <p className="text-primary">Portfolio</p>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Portfolio/>, document.getElementById('portfolio'));
```

Alternatively, you could define a function outside the component and pass it in using a prop called `prompt`. Here's an alternate `index.js` that does that:

```jsx
var promptFunc = function() { alert('hi'); };

var TitleBar = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    return(
     <div className="jumbotron">
      <div className="container">
      <kbd className="fullName">name name</kbd>
        <button onClick={this.props.prompt} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>
      </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TitleBar prompt={promptFunc}/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));

var Portfolio = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return(
      <p className="text-primary">Portfolio</p>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Portfolio/>, document.getElementById('portfolio'));
```

If you use the latter method, it's best practice to define some [propTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) for your component.